# looping through a data frame and exporting data

Tags: r, for-loop

I created a data frame (df) with x and Temp.

I need to solve two equations  (fb_T = 1.09^Temp and growth = (1 * fb_T)) where fb_T is calculated looping through Temp from each row of the data frame. Each fb_T is then used to calculate growth.

Ideally I want to create a data frame with x, Temp and the corresponding fb_T and growth so that I can plot it.

I tried (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) but for fb_T, I get the first value as 0 then the rest are all NA's and for growth I just get one value.

How can I get fb_T to loop through Temp in the data frame and the outputs of fb_T to loop through the growth equation?

```
 x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 Temp <- c(10, 8, 6, 5, 2)
 df <- cbind(x, Temp)

 init <- rep(NA_real_, n_steps+1)
 init[1] <- 0.
 fbt <- init

 for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
   #for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {


    fb_T = 1.09^Temp[i]
    growth = (1 * fb_T)
 }

fbt
growth
```

I manually calculated and expected output:

```
 x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 Temp <- c(10, 8, 6, 5, 2)
 fb_T <- c(2.367364, 1.992563, 1.6771, 1.538624, 1.1881)
 growth <- c(2.367364, 1.992563, 1.6771, 1.538624, 1.1881)
 df <- cbind(x, Temp, fb_T, growth)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- tibble(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Temp=c(10, 8, 6, 5, 2))
d %>% mutate(fb_T=1.09**Temp, Growth=fb_T)
d
# A tibble: 5 x 4
      x  Temp  fb_T Growth
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    10  2.37   2.37
2     2     8  1.99   1.99
3     3     6  1.68   1.68
4     4     5  1.54   1.54
5     5     2  1.19   1.19
```

The reason you get only one value for `fb_T` and `growth` in your code is that they are scalars.  each iteration of the loop overwrites the previous values.

I share @RonalShah's confusion over `growth = (1 * fb_T)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly since `^` is vectorised.

```
df <- data.frame(x, Temp)
df$fb_T <- 1.09^df$Temp
```

and since `growth` column is same as `fb_T` we can just copy it.

```
df$growth <- df$fb_T
df
#  x Temp     fb_T   growth
#1 1   10 2.367364 2.367364
#2 2    8 1.992563 1.992563
#3 3    6 1.677100 1.677100
#4 4    5 1.538624 1.538624
#5 5    2 1.188100 1.188100
```

---

If this is a part of bigger process and you want to do this in a loop we can do :

```
#Initialise new columns
df$fb_T <- NA
df$growth <- NA

#For every row
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
   df$fb_T[i] = 1.09^df$Temp[i]
   df$growth[i] = (1 * df$fb_T[i])
}
```

Comment: the main problem is that there are about 100 equations and the results from one output feeds into the next. the dataframe is also enormous. This is a subset that I am testing to learn how to loop through one variable in a data frame then use that output in the next equation. I will then need to apply this to all the other equations. Is it possible to have fb_T calculated by looping through the data frame then getting that output into the next equation?